# Arguments not adding together

Tags: javascript

//Solved

I am trying to add the parameters together and then divide it by 2 so I can pass the result into the sqrt method. After some trouble shooting I found it's only returning the last parameter of the function.

typeOf returned that the arguments are numbers so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
function areaTriangle(a,b,c) {
    let area, perimeter; 

    perimeter = (a + b + c)/2;
    //heron's formula
    area = Math.sqrt(perimeter * ((perimeter - a)  * (perimeter - b) * (perimeter = c)));

    return area;
}

//areaTriangle(3,3,9) perimeter returns 9(arg of c). Should be 7.5.
```

Comment: You have `(perimeter = c)` instead of `(perimeter - c)`.

Comment: Wow, gosh... thank you I got tunnel vision and got hung up on the formula thinking I misunderstood how arguments work... Thanks.

Comment: Also, you cannot have a triangle with side lengths of 3, 3 and 9, FYI.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! I was just posting it as 3,3,9 for my own trouble shooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`area = Math.sqrt(perimeter * ((perimeter - a)  * (perimeter - b) * (perimeter = c)));`

to

`area = Math.sqrt(perimeter * ((perimeter - a)  * (perimeter - b) * (perimeter - c)));`